# requirejs reload javascript file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I write a single web app using requirejs, i have no idea if reload js file frequently, the previous file that object has created can remove by browser or must close the page?

main.js

```
btn.click(function() {
    require('./test.js?_r=' + Math.random());
});
```

test.js

```
var a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
   a.push('myname ' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might use the **require.undef** to undefine the module before reloading it. Here's the link to the official manual http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef.

But, generally speaking, RequireJS is not designed for reloading modules.